# Is there a way to connect to an external powerpivot data model from an Excel workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I'm looking for a way to connect to an external powerpivot data model from my current Excel workbook. I want to create multiple reports each in seperate Excel workbooks which should use a common powerpivot data model. However, I could neither find a possibility in Excel, with Powerpivot nor with Power Query. Does anyone have an idea how this problem can be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically, such problems are solved using MS Tabular. Instal Tabular on your computer, upload powerpivot model to it, and then connect as many Excel files as you need to the data model.

Comment: In my company we don't have MS Tabular/SSAS Tabular. But you lead me in on another direction. We have SharePoint. I will try to use this. Thanks! :-)